# JavaScript closure el.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

```
<div id="a">ONE</div>
<div id="b">TWO</div>
<div id="c">THREE</div>
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for ( var i = 0; i < el.length; i++ ) (function(){
 el.addEventListener("click",function(){
  console.log(this.id + " " + this.innerHTML);
 },false);
})(i);
```

Gives me error "el.addEventListener is not a function", what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `[i]` (index) in your code (it must be `el[i]`), thought `addEventListener` doesn't work in IE versions. To fix this problem you can do something like this:

```
function evt(elem,type,fn) { // element, event type, function
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + fn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`el` is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you've forgotten to use index:

```
el[i].addEventListener("click",function(){...};
```